# border-box hide pseudo elements in jQuery animation

Tags: jquery-animate, pseudo-element, border-box

I have this weird problem where pseudo elements won't appear when applying:

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

**Test Case 1:** http://jsfiddle.net/kGGuP/1/ - this worked as expected. Clicking the box will show the content and it will also show the "**arrow**" pseudo element.

**Test Case 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/XGGg4/ - I have added

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

to the CSS. As you can see, the "**arrow**" pseudo element won't appear anymore. This will occur in all browsers except Firefox.

Is there any fix for this other than removing the **box-sizing:border-box;** ? I really don't want to remove this rule.

**Additional Info:**

Only **.toggle() with parameters** and **.slideToggle()** seems to have this problem.

If using **.toggle() without parameters** and **.fadeToggle()**, it work fine.

Comment: I ended up adding the pseudo element on the "toggle" trigger rather than on the animated content element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/XGGg4/1/

i have made small changes in CSS file check that out with code as you wished

you could have used

```
*{
    -moz-box-sizing:content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
    box-sizing:content-box;
}
```

Above code will also help with your code

Comment: I won't change it to `position:fixed`, it needs to be absolute so that it will not scroll. Btw, it's only a part of a long content so fixed position must not be applied here.

Comment: @Ramil - You can use content-box instead of border-box in your code..

Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/XGGg4/2/

Comment: That would cause a lot of trouble for the existing layout, i.e. borders, paddings and margins of the other elements.

Comment: ^ Well, that's really the problem because when I set a negative top position, it cuts off (if having an animation). I can't also use it because I really need the look in Test Case 1.

Comment: Exactly I can see your problem

Answer (score 0):

check this out http://jsfiddle.net/XGGg4/5/

Adding

```
*{
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Really screws your code, instead you can set `box-sizing:border-box;` to every individual element. that will do the magic for you.

Comment: From my original post: "Is there any fix for this other than removing the box-sizing:border-box; ? I really don't want to remove this rule."

Comment: This rule is not removed indeed it is implemented to each element separately and then its working fine check that link once again